# Errors during installation SQL Server Management Studio (ssms) on 64-bit Windows7

Tags: installation, ssms, sql-management-studio

I have been trying to install SQL Server Management Studio (ssms) on a 64-bit Windows7 for two days now and it just doesn't work.

On a otherwise completely clean 64-bit Windows7 system I get the following error

```
 SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error: 
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

Steps done right before the error were :

```
- run SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU (v10.0.1600.22) as administator 
- On the SQL Server Installation Center (the landing page) select Installation > new SQL Server stand-alone or add features
- for "Sql Server 2008 Setup" Setup Support Rules (all passed) : click OK
- for "Sql Server 2008 Setup" Product Key  : click Next
- for "Sql Server 2008 Setup" License Terms : Accept and click next
- for "Sql Server 2008 Setup" Setup Support Files : click Install
```

*I'm hoping anyone can guide me into the correct direction as I have no idea what to do next..*

Comment: If you look at the log files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log, you may find additional insight into the specific error and what is causing it.  But what I might suggest instead is to see if you can get the 2008 R2 SSMS install.  It has better compatibility with Win7 64 and can still be used to connect to 2008 databases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was already trying it with the Microsoft Web Platform Installer and selected the "Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express with SP1" there. That's perhaps the same as the version you refer to? (the SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU download in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer had version 10.50.2500.0) ? It just finished succesfully :)

Comment: @BBlake If you set your comment as answer I'll accept and add the comment that I used webpi to install that. (I see now I could have downloaded it here too: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the log files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log, you may find additional insight into the specific error and what is causing it. But what I might suggest instead is to see if you can get the 2008 R2 SSMS install. It has better compatibility with Win7 64 and can still be used to connect to 2008 databases

Answer (score 0):

As BBlake indicated it had to do with the version I was trying to install. That older version was not compatible with 64-bit Windows 7.

*Installation with the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.5 worked.*

In webpi I just went to Products > Database and selected the ***"Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express with SP1"*** there. It installed without any issues.

After installation I checked the version of  SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU used by webPI in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer and it was version ***10.50.2500.0***. Strangely enough it seems webPi installed the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727) and not the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP1 - Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26729). Not sure why webPI calls the product SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express with SP1, but it worked !